# CitiBank CC application

Tags: credit-card, scams, application-process

I have applied for a Citibank CC to consolidate my other 2 cc. This was a recommendation by Credit Karma.  I am working on my credit as it is not the greatest.  I have received a letter from Citibank requesting more information.

They are requesting I send a copy of one of the following for each income source I have:
- Most recent W2 forms
- Most recent pay stub, w/name, SS# & the date within 30 days.

Is this a common procedure?  I have never been asked to give out this kind of information to a cc for approval.

Comment: Income verification is a part of many credit decisions, less common with credit cards, but as you mentioned, your score is not the greatest, so some extra verification on their part makes sense.

Comment: Googled the address you're supposed to send it to.  That'll tell you whether or not it's a scam.

Comment: Note that taking out _more_ credit cards may not be the best way to improve your credit score - in fact it may _hurt_ your score.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it common practice for credit card company to demand to see your income tax forms?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/141893/is-it-common-practice-for-credit-card-company-to-demand-to-see-your-income-tax-f)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Citibank wants verification that you have  consistent income and can - in good faith - pay your debt.

As a precaution, verify the address and/or fax number and/or email address you’ll be sending documents to. If you can, go into a branch and submit the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that your current score is "not the greatest" is why they asked for more info. Is it common? Probably not for those who have a credit report that shows a high ability to repay the debt.

Congrats on taking that first step. A good score will save you a lot of time and money in the future. You can do the math, the savings on even 1/2% lower rate on a mortgage can be huge.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to give an answer from personal experience. I got this exact same letter (When applying for a Citi Rewards+ card).

I phoned Citi at their main phone number (not the one in the letter), and had a representative there confirm that the letter is fully legitimate and is sent routinely to many credit card applications with them. They also confirmed that the specific documents required by the letter is not an exhaustive list and they will accept any reasonable proof of your income from each source.

I sent the requested documents in the mail (in my case a W2 as well as a letter from my stock broker confirming my dividend income) and a few days later received a reply (both an email and a letter) confirming that the documents were satisfactory and I had been approved.

**So tldr, this letter is routinely sent by Citi and is entirely legitimate. If you are worried call Citi at their registered number and they can confirm from the application code if they really sent a letter.**